# Grouping based on person, item, and store

Tags: python, python-3.x

My concern is regarding my code not running in python 3.5, it runs perfectly fine in python 2.7.

The question is we need to group the contents based on:

1. person
2. item
3. store

The contents in the file `1511.txt` are:

```
david book 8 walmart
mike book 5 kroger
david food 3  walmart
mary food 11 target
```

Output:

```
'mike': 5, 'mary': 11, 'david': 11
'food': 14, 'book': 13
'kroger': 5, 'walmart': 11, 'target': 11
mike 5
mary 11
david 11
number of items sold by mike is 5
number of items sold by mary is 11
number of items sold by david is 11
total number of food sold 14
total number of book sold 13
total number of items sold by kroger is 5
total number of items sold by walmart is 11
total number of items sold by target is 11
```

When I try to run the same program in python 3.5, it given the below output with the error:

```
'mike': 5, 'david': 11, 'mary': 11
'food': 14, 'book': 13
'target': 11, 'walmart': 11, 'kroger': 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\putch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\1511prognew.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(str(d.keys()[i]+" "+str(d.values()[i])))
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

This is my code, how can I modify this code to run in Python 3.5?

```
d={}
p={}
q={}
with open("1511.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        a=line.split()
        l,m,n,o=str(a[0]), str(a[1]), int(a[2]), str(a[3])
        d.setdefault(l,[]).append(n)
        p.setdefault(m,[]).append(n)
        q.setdefault(o,[]).append(n)

d=dict((key,sum(val)) for key,val in d.items())
p=dict((keys,sum(values)) for keys,values in p.items())
q=dict((keys,sum(values)) for keys,values in q.items())
print (d)
print (p)
print (q)

for i in range(0,len(d)):
    print(str(d.keys()[i]+" "+str(d.values()[i])))

for i in range(0,len(d)):
    print("number of items sold by "+d.keys()[i]+" is " +str(d.values()[i]))

for j in range(0,len(p)):
    print("total number of "+str(p.keys()[j])+" sold "+str(p.values()[j]))

for j in range(0,len(q)):
    print("total number of items sold by "+str(q.keys()[j])+" is "+str(q.values()[j]))
```

Comment: When you say "Python 3.7" are we to assume that you mean "Python 3.5"?

Comment: sorry, I ment Python 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dict.keys() no longer returns a list, a simpler way to write the print statements would be this:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print("{} {}".format(k,v))
```

Alternatively you could just use `list(dict.keys())` but the method I showed is more clear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943990/python-code-to-find-all-persons-based-on-qty-of-books-sold/40944072#40944072

Comment: I am unable to understand it.