# Python code to find all persons based on qty of books sold

Tags: python

> Hi, i got stuck with the below code, while I was trying to find solution for the question:
> Find all persons based on quantity of books sold.
>
> below is the content of the file 1711.txt

- david book 05 walmart
- emily book 10 kroger
- jason food 11 target
- david food 20 kroger
- eva cloth 13 target
- david book 5 walmart

**the output should be something like : david sold 10 books to walmart**

- **eva sold 13 cloths to target**
- **david sold 20 food to kroger**

*below is the code that I wrote, please assist me to with the correct code to display the correct result,
Thanks!*

```
d={}
p={}
q={}

with open("1711.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        a=line.split()
        l,m,n,o=str(a[0]), str(a[1]), int(a[2]), str(a[3])
        d.setdefault(l,[]).append(n)
        p.setdefault(m,[]).append(n)
        q.setdefault(o,[]).append(n)

    d=dict((key,sum(val)) for key,val in d.items())
    print (d)
    print("----------------------")
    p=dict((keys,sum(values)) for keys,values in p.items())
    print (p)
    print("--------------------")

    q=dict((keeys,sum(valu)) for keeys,valu in q.items())
    print (q)
    print("----------------------------")

    for k, v in d.items():
        print("number of itmes sold by {} is {}".format(k,v))
    print("------------------------------")

    for k, v in q.items():
        print("number of itmes in {} is {}".format(k,v))
    print("------------------------------")

    for k, v in p.items():
        print("total number of {} sold is {}".format(k,v))
    print("------------------------------")
```

Comment: If you are allowed to use an external library then you can do this in pandas in few steps I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want some nested dictionaries. The top level one should have keys that are all the names, and the values should be another dictionary.

Those dictionaries should have keys of the items, and the value should be another dictionary.

Finally, those dictionaries should have keys that have the store, and the values should be the number that have been sold to that store.

So then if you go: sales_dict["david"]["book"]["target"] it will spit out 10 for you.

edit: 
Here's the gist of creating the dictionary. I think you should probably refer to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries if you are still having issues.

```
d = {}
for line in f:
      a=line.split()
      l,m,n,o=str(a[0]), str(a[1]), int(a[2]), str(a[3])
      if l not in d:
            d[l] = {}
      if m not in d[l]:
            d[l][m] = {}
      if n not in d[l][m]:
            d[l][m][n] = 0
      d[l][m][n] += int(o)
```

Comment: can someone help me to modify the code to print the correct output